# OpenAPI generator add/generate annotation to ApiClient constructor

Tags: spring, annotations, openapi, resttemplate, openapi-generator

I use the newest OpenAPI generator 6.2.1 (https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to generate an ApiClient with the resttemplate library, which works quite well.

In my application I have now two different RestTemplate beans. So Spring does not know which one to use in the ApiClient constructor.

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.xyz.ApiClient required a single bean, but 2 were found

There is also a hint to solve the problem:

> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

I don't want to mark one of the beans with @Primary because it is not the primary bean wanted to be used.

I would like to add the @Qualifier to the generated ApiClient constructor like this:

```
    @Autowired
    public ApiClient(@Qualifier("myClientProperties") RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        init();
    }
```

How can I add the @Qualifier annotation to the generated constructor?

I read lots of openapi generator documentation but did not find anything helpful. There is a solution to add a annotation for models (additionalModelTypeAnnotations in the configOptions of OpenApi configuration).

I expect to generate a @Qualifier annotation to the ApiClient constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the component scanning for the generated classes. Assuming, your root package is 'my.root.package' and you generate the classes into 'my.root.package.generated', annotate your App / Config class with the following:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.root.package",
           excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,
                                                  pattern = "my.root.package.generated.*"))
```

Then, you can create own (qualified) ApiClients based on your rest templates:

```
@Bean("rest-template-1")
public RestTemplate restTemplate1() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@Bean("rest-template-2")
public RestTemplate restTemplate2() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@Bean("api-client-1")
public ApiClient apiClient1(@Qualifier("rest-template-1") RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    return new ApiClient(restTemplate);
}

@Bean("api-client-2")
public ApiClient apiClient2(@Qualifier("rest-template-2") RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    return new ApiClient(restTemplate);
}
```

With those different qualified ApiClients, you init your API classes as you need them.